# Irreducible representations of Sp(2)

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

I am looking for an explicit description of the finite dimensional irreducible representations of the classical Lie group $\text{Sp}(2) = \{A\in M_2(\mathbb{H})\,|\,A\overline{A}^T = I\}$.

I can easily find the above info for orthogonal groups and unitary groups (the representations coming from certain spaces of harmonic polynomials) but cannot seem to find such a description for the groups $\text{Sp}(n)$.

In particular I am aware that the irreducible representations of $\text{Sp}(2)$ are classified by Young diagram parameters $(a,b)$ with $a\geq b \geq 0$ but I would like to compute with such spaces so need an explicit description if possible.

Comment: Are you talking about complex representations? Also, please make precise what you mean by "explicit description". There are many descriptions around of varying degrees of explicitness (standard monomial theory, crystal bases, LS-paths etc.). There are also a realizations as harmonic polynomials.

Comment: Yes, I wish to know about complex representations. As for explicit, I simply mean any vector space I can generate and compute the action of $\text{Sp}(2)$ on, e.g. spaces of harmonic polynomials.

Comment: Sp(2) also goes by the name Spin(5).

Comment: I have seen this mentioned but could you explain what the irreducible representations of Spin(5) are?

Comment: What about the advice given in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/141024/explicit-realization-of-irreducible-representations-of-simple-lie-algebras?

Comment: I am not after representations of the Lie algebra since I don't know (explicitly/computationally) how to go from the Lie group to the Lie algebra. Is there a simple answer to my question? Is the representation with Young diagram $(a,b)$ given by homogeneous polynomials in some number of variables that are harmonic with respect to some differential operator?

Comment: If you just want any old realisation of the representation that you can do computations with, then you could try using the built-in functionality in Magma for computing explicit models of Lie group representations: see https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1195#13319. (The chief difficulty I've found in working with this is that it's a pain to construct *elements* of Lie groups in Magma; e.g. there is no direct way to pass from a 2x2 matrix to a GrpLieElt representing an element of GL(2).)

Comment: Thanks David, this was actually my initial issue. I am trying to compute the action of Hecke operators on algebraic forms for such a group (well...over an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$). A trace formula exists but it isn't practical (already for $T_{\langle 2 \rangle}$ one has to compute roughly $2.5$ million character values). For "small" weight it seems more plausible to find the space of forms directly and calculate the action explicitly (there are only say $85$ Hecke representatives for $T_{\langle 2 \rangle}$). My main issue is in setting up the representation so that magma lets me act.

Comment: Then again, it may just be that I am being silly and magma can do exactly what I want!

Comment: Isn't Sp(2) as the same as Spin(5)?

Answer (score 6):

Consider  the   Lie algebra $\frak{sp}(n)$ of the symplectic group  ${\rm Sp}(n)={\rm Sp}(n; \mathbb{C})\cap{\rm SO}(4n)$.

For $n=1$, let us denote by $V$ the representation of $\frak{sp}(1)$ on $\mathbb{C}^{2}$. Then, any irreducible $\frak{sp}(1)$-representation is isomorphic to some symmetric power ${\rm Sym}^{p}V$ of $V$.

For $n>1$ let us denote by $W$ the $2n$-dimensional complex representation of $\frak{sp}(n)$. Then, the symmetric powers ${\rm Sym}^{p}W$ are also irreducible. But not the exterior powers $\Lambda^{p}W$. Let us denote the kernel of the contraction $\Lambda^{p}W\to \Lambda^{p-2}W$ induced by the invariant 2-form on $W$, by $\Lambda_{0}^{p}W$.  For $p\leq n$ one can show that this submodule $\Lambda_{0}^{p}W$ is also irreducible. One can moreover define the modules ${\rm Ker}\{\Lambda^{2}({\rm Sym}^{2}W)\to {\rm Sym}^{2}W\}$ and  ${\rm Ker}\{\Lambda^{2}({\Lambda}^{2}_{0}W)\to {\rm Sym}^{2}W\}$, but  for $n=2$ the second $\frak{sp}(n)$-module is trivial. Some details can be found in the classical  book of Simon Salamon, ''Riemannian geometry and holonomy groups''. In particular, for ${\rm Sp}(2)$   see pages 80-84. Finally notice that  since $\frak{sp}(2)\cong\frak{so}(5)$, the spin representation of ${\rm SO}(5)$ is isomorphic to the standard representation $W$ of ${\rm Sp}(2)$ and the standard representation of ${\rm SO}(5)$ is isomorphic with $\Lambda_{0}^{2}W$.  Of course, using the LiE program you can take a quick view of  the complex irreducible representations of ${\rm Sp}(2)$, in terms of highest weights.

**added**  The irreducible representation of ${\rm Sp}(2)$
  with highest weight (2, 2) is of dimension 81. Since ${\rm Sp}(2)$
 is connected and simply-connected, it coincides wth ${\rm Spin}(5)$.
Now, this irreducible representation is identified with the isotropy representation of the homogeneous space ${\rm SO}(14)/{\rm SO}(5)$,  which is strongly isotropy irreducible. Notice finally that also the coset   ${\rm Spin}(10)/{\rm Sp}(2)$  is   a strongly isotropy irreducible space (of dimension 35). Here, the isotropy representation has highest weight (2, 1).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know this much already but wonder say what the irreducible representation of highest weight $(2,2)$ is (this should come from Young diagram $(4,2)$).

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I get that this quotient has dimension 81 and that we act on it by the adjoint action but I just have two more questions. What is the explicit isomorphism $\text{Sp}(2) \rightarrow \text{SO}(5)$ and how are we viewing this as a subgroup of $\text{SO}(14)$?

Comment: Alternatively what model am I going to need to use for the Lie algebra?

Comment: Yes, I have seen this but have no idea how it helps me to construct an explicit isomorphism...also doesn't the isotropy rep need the Lie algebra to act? If so this creates another issue since I have no way computationally of passing from $SO(5)$ to it's Lie Algebra (unless I am being stupid).

Comment: The Lie group ${\rm Sp}(2)$   is the double covering of ${\rm SO}(5)$.
In particular, $\frak{sp}(2)=\frak{so}(5)$ and   and ${\rm Sp}(2)\cong{\rm Spin}(5)$,  see for example Theorem 5.20, p.83 of the book: Topology of Lie Groups, I and II by Mamoru Mimura and Hirosi Toda.

Comment: Just for information: if you compose the action of Sp(2) on $S^7$ with the Hopf fibration to $S^4$, you get a linear action on $S^4$. This is a way to explicitly construct the double cover $Sp(2)\to SO(5)$.

Comment: What is special about Spin(10)/Sp(2) as a strongly isotropy irreducible space in your argument? (Why do you mention it?) Thanks!

Comment: You mention the book by Simon Salamon as a reference for your statements for Sp(n). Can you provide a reference for the fact that $S^p(W)$ and $\Lambda^p_0(W)$ are irreducible?